# Sum of diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

The idea is to calculate sum of diagonals 
example [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] the correct answer would be [1,5,9][3,5,7] = total 30

```
def sum_of_matrix(data):
    arr_solver = []
    counter = 0
    counter2 = -1
    while counter < len(data):
        arr_solver.append(data[counter][counter])
        arr_solver.append(data[counter][counter2])
        counter += data[counter][counter2]
        counter2 -= data[counter][counter]
    return sum(arr_solver)
```

This is my todays interview question I had, is this a good solution to a question?
My idea was to implement a graph and calculate path, but that'd take waaaaay too long and probably wouldn't be able to implement it on the go.

Comment: Your example does not work. `sum_of_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` aborts with `IndexError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm that you have implemented right now just raises an `IndexError`.

I'll suggest a slightly different way to do is that will have `O(n)` speed and `O(1)` memory, where `n` is the side length of the matrix.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that's the fastest you can get.

```
def sum_of_diags(matrix):
    # Perhaps add some type checking first,
    # check whether the matrix is empty

    size = len(matrix[0])
    if size == 1:
        # What do you want to do with a single-element matrix?
        return matrix[0][0]*2

    # Just initializing the sum and adding to it
    # reduces the space complexity from O(n) to O(1)
    diag_sum = 0

    for i in range(size):
        # First, we sum over the main diagonal
        # from [0, 0] to [size, size]
        diag_sum += matrix[i][i]

        # Second, we sum over the other diagonal,
        # going from [0, size] to [size, 0]
        diag_sum += matrix[i][size-i-1]
    return diag_sum
```

Test it:

```
>> m = np.arange(1, 9).reshape((3, 3))
>> m
array([[1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]])

>> sum_of_diags(m)
30
```

Comment: Just for fun, `[size-i-1]` can be changed to `[-i-1]`.
I'm genuinely not sure which is clearer though.

Comment: Im not sure if I can update my code, but i fixed it a little bit on my own and it works(guess I made some typo or something not sure). But your solution is definitely more efficient, so I appreciate it !
Found the typo, variables(counter and counter2) have to increment and decrement by 1, my bad!

Comment: Why special case for `size == 1`? It works perfectly fine without it.

Comment: Totally agree @MathiasEttinger, just thought it might be good to be aware of the possibility.

Comment: @Josiah The advantage of `[-i-1]` is that you can do `for i, row in enumerate(matrix)` and not bother with `size` at all. Effectively being able to reduce the function body to `sum(row[i] + row[-i-1] for i, row in enumerate(matrix))`.